# How to click on textbox in IE browser

Tags: excel, vba

I am unable to click on following Text box by Excel-vba with below script.

```
myURL = "http://172.16.118.23/ibc_search.php"
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.Navigate myURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set htmlDoc = MyBrowser.Document

htmlDoc.all.account_no.Value = "040002654564"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: links are sourced to your local drive, so they do not work here.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Run-time error '438':

Comment: Object doesn't support to this property or method

Comment: Yes it is and in screenshot displaying codes of navigation tab 'Search Account' in which textbox available but I am not getting a path to trigger it.

Comment: Any other solution?